# eventuality of <your passport being stolen> <stealing (of) your passport>

Tags: present-participles

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/eventuality?q=eventuality):
**(1)** In the eventuality of **your passport being stolen**, contact the embassy at once.
My variants:
**(2)** In the eventuality of **stealing your passport**, contact the embassy at once.
**(3)** In the eventuality of **stealing of your passport**, contact the embassy at once.

Could you tell me please what difference is between (1), (2) & (3)?

Answer (score 2):

1 is passive.  "...your passport being stolen..." means that {someone} steals your passport

2 and 3 are active, and so the implied subject is "{you} steal your passport", which is ridiculous.  3 is the same as 2, it just uses a possessive form, which is possible when the verb is a gerund.

Comment: You regard (1) as "_in the eventuality of your passport being stolen **by someone**_" and not as "_in the eventuality of your passport being stolen **by yourself**_".  At the same time you regard (2) as "_in the eventuality of **you** stealing your passport_" but not as "_in the eventuality of **someone** stealing your passport_". Why do you see it the way that in (1) "someone" is implied whereas in (2) "you" is implied? To me (1) & (2) are analogous to each other and therefore the words implying in them must also be analogous: i.e. either "you" in both cases or "someone" in both cases. Thanks

Comment: That's just the way the language works. A phrase like **stealing your passport** requires some mention of the perpetrator, otherwise it implies that you did it.